# Capistrano 2: Capistranos shared/image folder is empty after running cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, svn, capistrano

I am on capistrano version 2.I have store users images in rails public/image folder,but on remote server i want to put images store inside public/image folder into shared/image folder.

My code for capistrano's deploy.rb file is as below.

```
set :shared_children, shared_children +  %w{public/images}

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_uploads'
namespace :deploy do
  task :symlink_uploads do

    run "ln -nfs /home/ubuntu/shared/image /home/ubuntu/current/public/image"

  end
end
```

With the above code when i run `cap deploy` the symlink and code get updated successfully but my shared/images folder doesn't contain any image.
I check my svn repo and images are present in public/image folder then why those images are not coming in shared/image folder after running `cap deploy` command??

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: Try use this  `run "ln -nfs /home/ubuntu/shared/image /home/ubuntu/#{release_path}/public/image"`

Comment: @Зелёный - i tried it but the issue is still there.